# How to make a confirm password field?

Tags: chronoforms

I have a user registration form made with ChronoForms. How do I make a password confirmation field?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In ChronoForms version 5, create two fields such as "Password" and "Retype Password".

Under the "Designer" tab, edit the "Retype Password" field, click on the "Validation" tab and enter the other field name i.e. "Password" in the "Confirm" field where the tool tip says, "Used to validate the value of this field against the value of another, enter the other field's ID" (see image below).

Validation will then be handled automatically for you.

Earlier versions of ChronoForms do not have this feature and need to be custom coded.

[image]

Comment: It worked very well. But only one more thing, when i put a different password in the confirm field, it displays a message, that is in english, different of my native language, how can i change this message?

Comment: Edit your form and under the "Validation" tab, there are more than 20 language options to choose from. For more details see: http://www.chronoengine.com/faqs/2590

Comment: Now it's perfect! Thanks a lot for the help and your time! Thankful ;)